# Compact Framework - Mapping Keyboard key to button click event

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am working on a wizard for a compact framework application.  The wizard has a next and previous button at the bottom left and bottom right of the screen.  How would I go about binding a keypad buttons to fire the next and previous buttons.  The device that will be running the application has keypad buttons the sit directly below the next and previous buttons and I want to intercept the key events from these buttons and trigger the next and previous button click in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention if it's a custom Windows CE device or a more "standard" Windows Mobile device.

- For a Windows CE device, the key can likely be intercepted with combinations of the form's `KeyPreview` property, the form's `KeyDown` event, the `HardwareButtons` from `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` and the native `AllKeys` function.
- For a Windows Mobile device, I'm pretty sure you need to install a keyboard hook to catch the two buttons below the screen...

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am not really sure what the difference between a ce and windows mobile device is.  The device is running windows mobile 6.0 and has a keyboard layout like a mobile phone.  The SDK that comes with the device does have keyboard mapping and event triggering classes, but I was hoping for a more general approach.  What I have resorted to at the moment is trapping the keydown event on all textbox etc controls and getting the keycode that way.

Comment: @Andrew: If it's running Windows Mobile 6, then it's a Windows Mobile device, of course. You didn't mention that, and since the Compact Framework runs any Windows CE device, it could as well have been an industrial custom device.